# Plot a bar graph with means of values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet-grid

I am plotting a facet bar graph of `y` against `class` by `quantity`. Here is the code to produce the dataframe:

```
set.seed(99)
y<-sample(1:100,50,replace=TRUE)
class<-rep(c(letters[1:5]),times=10)
quantity<-as.factor(rep(c(5,10,15,20,25),each=10))
df<-data.frame(y,class,quantity)
```

And here's the code to produce the graph:

```
ggplot(df,aes(class,y))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(.~quantity)
```

The current plot gives me a sum of `y` against `class`. I want to find the mean of `y` against `class` by `quantity`. How can I do that?

Thank you!

(*example taken from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-bar-chart-using-ggplot2-with-facets-that-are-in-the-order-of-the-data-in-r)*)

Comment: Instead of `geom_bar`, use `stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar")`. See the linked duplicate for more explanation.

Comment: Don't use "identity". You can summaize with mean: `geom_bar(stat="summary", fun=mean)+`

Comment: @GregorThomas Actually I think that latest version of ggplot2 doesn't use `fun.y` any more. I think it's just `fun` now. (at least it didn't work for me)

Comment: I didn't test the answer at the old question... sounds like it need updating!

Comment: Thank you both! These were helpful!